# Set StackPane background image

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to set background image autoresized with StackPane.

I tried this:

```
StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
Image im = new Image(Dashboardpanel.class.getResource("/images/11.jpg").toExternalForm()); 
stackPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(im, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, BackgroundSize.DEFAULT)));
```

But the image is not auto-resized when I resize the StackPane. The image is repeated to fill the gap. How I can resize the image just as the Stackpane no matter how I extend the StackPane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the default BackgroundSize, create a new [BackgroundSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundSize.html#BackgroundSize-double-double-boolean-boolean-boolean-boolean-) and use the contain and cover arguments of the BackgroundSize constructor.

For example (and I just wrote this by reading the javadoc, I didn't test it):

```
new BackgroundSize(BackgroundSize.AUTO, BackgroundSize.AUTO, false, false, false, true);
```

I advise using a [CSS stylesheet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) for this kind of styling rather than coding the style in Java.

Comment: Is this correct? `stackPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(im, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, new BackgroundSize(BackgroundSize.AUTO, BackgroundSize.AUTO, 0, 0, false, true))));`? I get incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean